# nagios server not read proper exit code

Tags: nagios

hi my script is not showing proper exit code on server side.

```sh
SERVICENAME=`/etc/init.d/$NAME status| awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\.//g' | grep -i running | sed 's/\s//g'|tail -n 1`

if [ "${SERVICENAME}" == "Running" -o "${SERVICENAME}" == "running" ]
then
        STATUS="OK";
        EXITSTAT=0;
        elif [ "${SERVICENAME}" != "Running" -o "${SERVICENAME}" != "running" ]
        then
                STATUS="CRITICAL";
                EXITSTAT=2;
        else
                STATUS="WARNING";
                EXITSTAT=1;
        fi

echo "$STATUS- Service $NAME $EXITSTAT |Service $NAME=0;2;3"
exit $EXITSTAT
```

Comment: is there a reason you're not using an existing, well-written plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I see some errors in your script.
If you wish to give SERVICENAME the value of the command, you must add backquotes before and after:

```
SERVICENAME=`/etc/init.d/$NAME status| awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/\.//g' | grep -i unning | sed 's/\s//g'|tail -n 1`
```

Between `if` and `then` you must have a semicolon:

```
if [ "${SERVICENAME}" == "Running" -o "${SERVICENAME}" == "running" ]; then STATUS="OK"; EXITSTAT=0; elif [ "${SERVICENAME}" != "Running" -o "${SERVICENAME}" != "running" ]; then STATUS="CRITICAL"; EXITSTAT=2; else STATUS="WARNING"; EXITSTAT=1; fi
```

And voilà:

```
[root@test ~]# ./script
OK- Service slapd 0 |Service slapd=0;2;3 exit 0
```